# SQL Server hierarchy query for primary/secondary variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

This is going to be tough to explain, but essentially we have a table of user tracked activities..example:

```
customerid      Year    Month   Day team_name   Activityname
123456789   2017    6      1    CTM Officer     ECM Clean-up (EOI)
123456789   2017    6      1    CTM Officer     Investigation Simple
123456789   2017    6      1    CTM Officer     RM - Call Regular
123456789   2017    6      1    CTM Officer     RFI Response for Clarification
```

Each activity logged is a separate instance/row. What I've been told is that for example within these 4 activities, one is a primary and the other secondary. So let's say Investigation Simple is the primary, and the other 3 are the secondary.

What I've been asked to do is to look through all the data, and do analysis to see for every time a primary activity is tracked, how often we see the secondary activities also being tracked to ensure users are complying with their tracking requirements...

The tough part is that each activity is captured as it's own row. The only line of sight I have is which is primary and which is secondary. What I am trying to figure out is to perhaps pull volumes for the primary activity, and the corresponding volume of secondary activities. The thing is there's no way the data is structured in the database itself to simply set up such hierarchy when its just a bunch of activities.

What I've done so far is grouped the activity by customerid by day/month/year to see what activities were tracked for that customer on that day, under the assumption the customer does not call for two different requests (2 primary activities) in one day. Although it is possible I suppose. I hope I am making sense....

I am wondering if something like this is even possible...thanks.

Comment: Edit your question and show the desired results.

Comment: Do you have a "lookup" table with a list of all `Activityname`s and their types (primary/secondary)? Please create a simple http://sqlfiddle.com/ of you table / data setup

Comment: We have a list of the activities in a table but not if they are primary/secondary...this was manually done by someone on my team...we were thinking of using it as a lookup table but still wondering how we would group them together...

Comment: @BorisD'Souza - do one small step at a time. If you have a lookup table that can identify primary / secondary, then you can come up with queries to see correlation between them. Your question seems to be more about data analysis than actual SQL code. If true, maybe you should state that in your question.

Comment: Perhaps I am just trying to figure out the SQL code which will enable my further analysis...The thing is the secondary activities don't roll up to the primary activities in the mapping tables..it is simply just that they are labelled as primary or secondary...

Comment: @BorisD'Souza - RE: "secondary activities don't roll up to the primary activities" You made it quite clear the first time. RE: "trying to figure out the SQL code" - I am not aware of any resource where you can look this up and the problem as it stands is not defined well enough for people to give you code. See my first comment if you want some code (at least from me).